# R: loop inside kable with pipe while also piping output to next step (group_rows)

Tags: r, loops, pipe, kable

I'm using `kable` and I ceating tables for about 500 datasets, hence I'm trying to create one script and loop over it.  One thing I stump me is that I am using the `group_rows` option, though the number of groups will change between datasets.  How can one set up an R script to take this into account.

Here is my script currently using a normal loop inside the `kable` command which doesn't work...

[the dataset `grps` is predefined criteria to determine groups]

For the code below, the `grps` & `color` datasets are below.  They are not connected to `mtcars` at all:

```
grps <- 
structure(list(no.cars = c(2,1,2), maincars = c("Mazda", 
"Datsun", "Hornet"), start = c(1, 3, 4),
 end = c(2L, 3L, 5L)), .Names = c("no.cars", "maincars", 
"start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

color <- structure(list(color=c("#20324C", "#D2A8A4", "#FFC65A")),.Names = c("color"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

mtcars[1:5,] %>% 
    knitr::kable(format="html")%>% 
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
    for(g in 1:nrow(grps)){
        group_rows(grps$maincars[g], grps$start[g], grps$end[g],label_row_css = paste0("background-color: ",color[g,1],"; color: #F1F1F1;")) %>% .()
    } %>% as_image()
```

With that, it didn't create any groups.  I'm curious if there is another option I could try?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example? At the moment I would expect this not to work, since the `for`-loop is not connected to the mtcars-table....

Comment: Updated to include examples of `color` and `grps` datasets.  They are not currently connected to `mtcars`.  Though, I'm taking they should be?

Comment: Copy and paste on my part.... all okay in my actual script.

Comment: Try a non-pipe solution still using `for` loop (i.e., break every pipe as own obj `<- ...` line and pass result into next line).

Comment: To be clear, you are suggesting to create a loop outside of `kable` in which I create an object for every possible group_row? If so, how would I pipe them all together after?  Would I need to create a list or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a non-pipe solution:

```
sub <- mtcars[1:5,]
sub <- knitr::kable(sub, format="html")
sub <- kable_styling(sub, "striped", full_width = FALSE) 

for(g in 1:nrow(grps)){
   sub <- group_rows(sub, grps$maincars[g], grps$start[g], grps$end[g],
                     label_row_css = paste0("background-color: ", color[g,1],
                                            "; color: #F1F1F1;")
                    )
}

as_image(sub)
```

Alternatively to use pipes, incorporate a user-defined method:

```
run_group_rows <- function(x){
    for(g in 1:nrow(grps)){
       x <- group_rows(x, grps$maincars[g], grps$start[g], grps$end[g],
                         label_row_css = paste0("background-color: ", color[g,1],
                                                "; color: #F1F1F1;")
                       )
    }
    return(x)
}

mtcars[1:5,] %>% 
    knitr::kable(format="html")%>% 
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE) %>%
    run_group_rows() %>% 
    as_image()
```

Comment: Wow, that seems so easy.  Curious though, if I did a similar thing, say, but this time using `cell_spec`, this would need to be done differently as only one `cell_spec` is allowed per column. I believe, anyway.  However, I want to color each cell a different colour defined by another variable.  I tried an `ifelse` statement, but I didn't get that to work.

Comment: This sounds like you need to ask a different question. Did solution here work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks